# Setting up Online Booking form, getting this error - TypeError at /bookings/ 'OnlineForm' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Can anyone please help. I am currently working through a project where I am attempting to create a website for a fictitious restaurant, including an online booking form.
I am getting the following error message:
TypeError at /bookings/
'OnlineForm' object is not callable

I have watched a number of videos and read through the Django documentation and I still have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am new to Django so this is all learning for me. Any advice you can give would be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance

This is my code:

view.py:

```
class BookingForm(FormView):
    form_class = OnlineForm()
    args = {}
    def booking_view(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = OnlineForm(request.POST)
        
        return render(request, 'bookings.html')
```

models.py

```
OCCASION_CHOICE = (
    ('Birthday', 'BIRTHDAY'),
    ('Anniversary', 'ANNIVERSARY'),
    ('Graduation', 'GRADUATION'),
    ('Communion', 'COMMUNION'),
    ('Confirmation', 'CONFIRMATION'),
    ('Christening', 'CHRISTENING'),
    ('Date Night', 'DATE NIGHT'),
)

class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)],default='1', help_text='For parties of more than 10, please call us on 021 4569 782')
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    occasion = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=OCCASION_CHOICE, default='Birthday')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Booking


class OnlineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from .views import BookingForm
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'bookingsystem'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('bookings/', BookingForm.as_view(), name='bookings'),
    path('menus/', views.Menus.as_view(), name='menus'),
    path('edit_bookings', views.editBooking.as_view(), name='edit_bookings'),
]
```

bookings.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    
   <button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-success">Book Now</button>
</form>

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [django description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView), of FormView you do not have an option of defining your own POST method. Rewriting your view to

```
class BookingForm(FormView):
    template_name = 'bookings.html'
    form_class = OnlineForm
```

will solve the issue. Though you'll need to add a *form_valid* method to define actions to carryout when a form with valid data is submitted.

Comment: Hi Edwin that worked, thank you so much. I will have a look into the form_valid and get that sorted.
Thank you again for you help.